# How can I "collapse" multiple push notifications into one?

Tags: ios, push-notification

On Android, when supplying the same `id` in two calls to [`NotificationManager.notify`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html), only one notification will be shown in the notification drawer.

On BlackBerry, when supplying the same `tag` in two calls to [`Notification()`](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/v2_1/blackberry.notification.html), only one notification will be shown in the message hub.

What is the equivalent functionality on iOS?

We need to deliver certain push notifications multiple times to make the phone ring and vibrate multiple times, but we only want to have a single message visible on the lock screen.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @sasquatch: No. As far as I know, it's not possible.

Comment: This question may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413477/apple-push-notification-collapse-key-equivalent

Answer (score 1):

The method on iOS is very similar in concept to Android and BlackBerry. From Apple's APNs overview:

> To allow the coalescing of similar notifications, you can include a *collapse identifier* with the notification request.

Notifications with the same identifier will be collapsed on the receiving device.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1